# How to make an onehot tensor with every row of the tensor contains more than one '1'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I need to build a onehot tensor with every row of the tensor contains two '1', and I have got the index tensor, but how to build the tensor? I know that `onehot = tf.sparse_to_dense(index, tf.stack([batchsize,10]), 1.0, 0.0)`could finish that if the batchsize=1, but if batchsize>1, what should I do?
In other words, how to build the tensor:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

with the label:

```
[[1,3,5]
 [3,5,6]]
```

Comment: This should be done at data preparation time, before feeding data to tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
indices = [[1,3,5], [3,5,6]]
depth = 10
tmp_onehot_3D = tf.one_hot(indices, depth)
onehot_2D = tf.reduce_sum(tmp_onehot_3D, axis=1)
onehot_2D.eval()
```

Result:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not as concise as @Maosi Chen, but it also provides an alternative approach. The gist is to convert the slices to a 2d set of coordinates, then make a sparse tensor from those, and convert that to a dense tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf

slices = tf.constant([[1, 3, 5], [3, 5, 6]], dtype=tf.int64)
values = tf.ones_like(slices)

nrows = 2
ncols = 10

row_inds = tf.range(nrows, dtype=slices.dtype)

flattened_indices = tf.reshape(slices * nrows + row_inds[:, None], [-1])

twod_inds = tf.stack(
    [flattened_indices % nrows, flattened_indices // nrows], axis=1)

one_hot_sparse = tf.SparseTensor(
    twod_inds, values=tf.reshape(values, [-1]), dense_shape=(nrows, ncols))

one_hot_dense = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(one_hot_sparse, validate_indices=False)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(one_hot_dense))
```

Here is the output

```
[[0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0]]
```